# Multiple constraints on quadratic programming? - How to solve?

Tags: optimization, optimal-control, constraints, quadratic-programming

Assume that you are using `quadprog` command in MATLAB/Octave and you want to minimize this objective function:

$$\Phi_{min} = \frac{1}{2}X^TQX + c^TX$$

With subject to:

$$X_{min} \leq X \leq X_{max}$$

But I have the constraint

$$Y_{min} \leq AX \leq Y_{max},$$

where $A$ is a matrix. How can I solve that?

Comment: Which one do you have?

Comment: Yes, what is your other constraint?

Comment: @amsmath Both. Or is that impossible to have two lower and two upper bounds as constraints?

Comment: @mjw yes. It is my other constraint.

Comment: I don't get your question. So, what is your constraint?

Comment: @amsmath Look at the subjects.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson There you have two contraints that you say are used in the Matlab function. Remember: It's _you_ who wants help -- not me.

Comment: @amsmath Yes, I know there is my question. Posted it for few minutes ago. But the MATLAB command only says lb <= x <= ub as constraint. That's one constraint for upper and lower bound. Not bounds.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson You haven't even thought about the possibility that your question might be misunderstandable, right? I still don't get it...

Comment: @amsmath No. I assume that even I not write correct math and not finding the correct words. Other will still understand what I'm looking for. That's called a question.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson Is it right that you´ve problems with your $\textrm{second}$ constraint? Please clarify.

Comment: @callculus I don't know how to apply my second constraint. Because when I looked at `quadprog` they only show that the lower and upper bound constraint is only one constraint.

Comment: It seems like [quadprog](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/quadprog.html) also supports constraints of the type $Ax\leq b$ via the third and fourth argument.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson I'll edit your question because it is not understandable in the way you wrote it. BTW, start doubting yourself. Makes you a better person.

Comment: @LinAlg Thank you for the information. I know that, but the problme is the <=. It would be perfect if it was $b_{min} \leq Ax \leq b_{max}$ :)

Comment: $-Ax\le -b_{\min}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rephrase
$$y_{\min} \leq Ax \leq y_{\max},$$
as
$$\begin{pmatrix}A \\ -A\end{pmatrix}x \leq \begin{pmatrix}y_{\max} \\ -y_{\min}\end{pmatrix},$$
which is in the format of what quadprog accepts.

Comment: Well, the $X$ vector need to have the same dimension as $\begin{pmatrix}y_{\max} \\ -y_{\min}\end{pmatrix}$, so I think I will use $Ax \leq y_{max}$ only.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson why do the dimensions need to be the same?

Comment: It's because of the $Q$ is square and have the same dimension as $c^T$.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson that holds true for any QP and sets the number of columns in the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}A \\ -A\end{pmatrix}$. The number of rows (= number of constraints) is arbitrary.

Comment: Yes. but if [A;-A] have a higer dimension than  $Q$, i will get an error from quadprog.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson you are not supplying them as Aeq/beq arguments, right? There should be no error. Would you mind sharing a brief code example?